# How to find string pattern in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

Here is a string like this in Java.

```
String string="abc$[A]$def$[B]$ghi";
```

I want to search words that are located in `$[*]$` pattern. The result of above the string is `A`, `B`.

Comment: [Regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) is any good to you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
    String s = "abc$[A]$def$[B]$ghi";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\$\\[.*?\\]\\$");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while(m.find()){
        String b =  m.group();
        System.out.println(">> " +b.substring(2, b.length()-2));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression. In Java, you can use the [Pattern class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions for that. Take a look at the classes [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html).

The regular expression you would use in that case would be:

```
\$\[.*?\]\$
```

Alternatively, you could work with [String.indexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) and [String.substr](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29).