# How to search inside an String array for Names using created database

Tags: java, arrays, methods

Total noob here.

I just started learning java and would like to create a program so my teacher does not need to count everyone just to figure out who is missing.

For this, I would need input data.
We use teams to learn java so the people who are attending could write something in chat so the teacher can copy/paste this as input data for my program.

This is what I already have:

```
    String names = "Tupac Shakur,Randy Bobandy,Michael Scott,Randy Marsh,Leslie Knope,you mum gey,no u";

    String[] arr = names.split(",");
    System.out.println("Bot NaniPoonani: Who is here Tool v1 ");
    System.out.println("Bot NaniPoonani: Copy/paste the chat data here: ");
    Scanner inputNames = new Scanner(System.in);
    String ScanNames = inputNamen.next();


    String[] FilterdInputNames = ScanNamen.split(Arrays.toString(arr));

    String[] FilterdNames = names.split(",");

    for (String ss : arr);
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println(" ");

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(FilterdInputNames));
}
```

This code did not work how I expected and I'm kinda blocked.
The second problem is the chat input is filled with not need data, here is an example:

```
> [Yesterday 4:44 PM] Tupac Shakur
    
Ja Patrick..
​[Yesterday 4:45 PM] James Bond
    cya
​[Yesterday 4:45 PM] Nikola Tesla
    laters
​[Yesterday 4:45 PM] Pewdie Pie
    
ok
​[Yesterday 4:45 PM] Huge Anus
    Bedankt, MabOI!
​[Yesterday 4:45 PM] Humong Gus
    
Dank u wel !! (smile)
​[Yesterday 4:45 PM] Boby Lee
    Tot morgen
​[Yesterday 4:45 PM] Mister Lahey
    tot donderdag
<https://teams.microsoft.com/l/message/19:10fe21fc866846639f2e669602bbb1b5@thread.tacv2/1617115470132?tenantId=73c18a3-ce77-4292-94ad-b1ce04645b22&amp;parentMessageId=1617089369488&amp;teeatedTime=1617115470132>
> Blockquote
```

My first thought was that I could use .split to fill an array with each name using the not needed data

[Yesterday 4:44 P**M]** Tupac Shakur **(enter or /n )**

something like this:  `String[] FilterdInputNames = ScanNamen.split("M]" + "/n");`
But clearly, that's not how slipt works.

All advice is welcome since I am not even sure if I need to filter the not needed data.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Ask one question at the time.

Comment: You could try [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). Here is some discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636102/how-to-find-string-pattern-in-java